# Draw an arrow for a vector on the top of each of the turtles

Tags: netlogo

I wish to draw an arrow at the top turtle representing a vector denoted by

**[x1,y1]** . The vector is of unit magnitude and the size of the arrow should not exceed that of the turtle.
The vector is stored in a list with two elements.

I don't wish to use the shape editor in netlogo to shape as arrow and then point the turtle in the heading denoted by the vector. The reason being I could draw one than 1 arrows for each turtle.

**Edit:**

*Desired:*

[image]

*Bryan's answer gives the following:*
[image]

**Edit 2:**

Video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SVcLg4Oyoc&t=23 for better explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

Make sure your turtles are all of one breed, say, `particles`, or whatever they represent. Create another turtles breed called `vectors` or something. These turtles are going to be the tip of your vectors but you'll use links to actually visualize the vectors. Now, you can create the vectors like so:

```
ask particles [
  hatch-vectors 1 [
    create-link-from myself
    hide-turtle
  ]
]
```

To update the position of the vectors (given that the vector itself is stored in a turtle variable `vec`), you can do:

```
ask particles [
  let abs-x xcor + first vec
  let abs-y ycor + last vec
  ;; Since the particle is linked to the vector by a directed link, it's an out-link-neighbor
  ask out-link-neighbors [ setxy abs-x abs-y ]
]
```

Edit in response to update:

That's tougher, since link shape editing is more limited than turtle shape editing. One possibility would be to set the shape of the vector turtles to an arrow head (you could either create a new such shape, or the default turtle shape could suffice). Rather than hiding the `vectors`, you'd then point them in the right direction. This can easily be done by having them face their link-partner and then turn around.

You may also want to switch from directed to undirected links to get rid of the arrow in the link itself. This should only involve minor code changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please check the edit in the question above it would be better understanding about the problem.

Comment: But the arrow won't relate to the magnitude of the vector only it's direction, and it is undesirable to change the size of the agents as I use for some computation. I have also added a new video of simulations which closely matches what I am trying to achieve. Please have a look.

Comment: What do you mean? The length of the arrow would be exactly equal to the magnitude of the vector under both systems I have described.

Comment: But won't you have to change the size of the turtle in the second case to achieve that? Something I don't find desirable.

Comment: No, the vector-turtle size can remain the same size. The distance between it and the agent (bridged by a link) indicates magnitude.

Comment: Are you referring the first solution, not the edit one? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am referring to both. They are the same except that the second uses a turtle as the arrow head. The link size (vector body) changes length with vector magnitude in both solutions as expected.

Comment: Can you explain the second approach with some code, it would easier to understand.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the first approach except that: 1) The turtles at the end of the links are visible instead of hidden, 2) the turtles at the end of the links should point away from the particle they're linked to (`face one-of link-neighbors rt 180`), 3) use undirected links instead of directed links to get rid of the (now redundant) arrow on the link.